# Is there an equivalent method for Ruby's `.dig` but where it assigens the values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, parameters

Let's say we're using `.dig` in Ruby like this:

```
some_hash = {}
some_hash.dig('a', 'b', 'c')
# => nil
```

which returns `nil`

Is there a method where I can assign a value to the key `c` if any of the other ones are present? For example if I wanted to set `c` I would have to write:

```
  some_hash['a'] = {} unless some_hash['a'].present?
  some_hash['a']['b'] = {} unless some_hash['a']['b'].present?
  some_hash['a']['b']['c'] = 'some value'
```

Is there a better way of writing the above?

Comment: This is tenuous what if `some_hash['a']['b'] == 'cat'`? Then this becomes `'cat'['c'] = 'some_value'` which results in `some_hash['a']['b'] #=> 'some_valueat'`. Other likely outcomes `NoMethodError`, `TypeError`, `IndexError`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can be easily achieved when you initialize the hash with a default like this:

```
hash = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = Hash.new(&hash.default_proc) }
hash[:a][:b][:c] = 'some value'
hash
#=> {:a=>{:b=>{:c=>"some value"}}}
```

Setting nested values in that hash with nested defaults can partly be done with `dig` (apart from the last key):

```
hash.dig(:a, :b)[:c] = 'some value'
hash
#=> {:a=>{:b=>{:c=>"some value"}}}
```